# PHP PDO, binding params in foreach without &- strange results

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I found a strange behaviour of PDO.
When i use this code

```
$url_array = ['111', '222'];
foreach ($url_array as $key => $url){
    $values[] = '(:url'.$key.', :referer'.$key.')';
}
$query = implode(',', $values);

$pdo = $this->createPDO();
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_list` (`num`) VALUES " . $query);

foreach ($nums as $key => $num){     <==================
     $sth->bindParam(':url'.$key, $num);
}
$sth->execute();
```

I get 222, 222 in my table. But when i add & to the 2-d foreach- i get 111, 222 in my table

```
$url_array = ['111', '222'];
foreach ($url_array as $key => $url){
    $values[] = '(:url'.$key.', :referer'.$key.')';
}
$query = implode(',', $values);

$pdo = $this->createPDO();
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_list` (`num`) VALUES " . $query);

foreach ($nums as $key => &$num){     <==================
     $sth->bindParam(':url'.$key, $num);
}
$sth->execute();
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: read the manual page on bindParam

Comment: The reason for your problem is because you used `bindParam` instead of `bindValue`. Two functions are different and for some weird reason, many people use `bindParam` when they actually need `bindValue`. As @YourCommonSense mentioned - read the manual, **check what it says for function parameters** and you'll notice why.